# Docke run volume root file ownership issue

Tags: php, docker, permissions, volume, mount

I'm having issues getting a mounted docker volume to use a user other than root.

Any files I create with this command:

`docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp php:8.1-cli php "$@"`

will always have root ownership on my host directory. Can someone clue me into how I get it to mount with my host's dir user? (Ex: /home/meisuser/mountedvolume

I've tried:

`docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp php:8.1-cli php "$@"`

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can you please share the output of this: `echo "$(id -u):$(id -g)"` ?

Comment: I get `1000:1000`